# My VBA code worked fine on IE9, but it doesn't work on IE11

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

I want to reset Setting on a page but click event is not fire on this Setting button.

It work fine on IE9 but when I upgrade to IE11 it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
Sub resetIEvalue()
Dim Browser As Object

    Set Browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With Browser

    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://stockprice.vn/a/statistics.html"


    While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Wend

    startTime = Timer
    Do While startTime + 1 > Timer
    Loop

    .document.getElementById("button-1025-btnInnerEl").Click ' <= This click event doesn't work on IE11.

End With
Browser.Quit
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the part where it doesn't work? What does it says?

Comment: Nothing happen when click event fired, and this is the html code part:
<span id="button-1025-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small">Chọn/Settings</span>

Comment: OK so Internet explorer doesn't open and navigate to the URL?

Comment: Yes, Internet explorer doesn't show a popup menu from Setting button.